# creating CSS dropdown menu with unlimited depth

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, html-lists, depth

How can i create a pure css dropdown menu with unlimited depth (many nested `ul`) support?

EDIT:
I can create the unlimited depth menu but after a depth the menu goes out of page.
I need to overcome this.  for example I thought about showing `ul` in odd depth at the right side and evens in the left side. but how? i don't know

Comment: Why do you think depth is limited? What is your need? Would you use javascript/jQuery?

Comment: What do you mean 'how'? What's the problem you're having? And, bear in mind that you're essentially asking for an infinite menu; this is unlikely to be a wonderful UI feature.

Comment: A pure CSS dropdown menu is a pure usability nightmare: at the microsecond your cursor is 1px off the menu, the latter closes itself.

Comment: @sinsedrix: because all of them i saw was designed for a limited depth support (for example maximum 5 nested ul). I need it for a joomla template and I say unlimited because i don't know how much is user's menu depth. yes i can but couldn't find a good jQuery menu plugin.

Comment: @DavidThomas: But all of css menu examples on the web I found supported limited number of nested `ul` elements!

Comment: Yeah, because if you nest too far you end up with a menu having to switch direction to fit in the view-port of the browser. Otherwise you can nest as deeply as you like, so long as you can account for the view-port dimensions. But you've still not explained what the problem you're having is. What have you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: @DavidThomas: my problem is exactly the direction switching. I edited the question to clearing it

Answer (score 1):

To be quite honest, if you need a menu that's supposed to be *used*, you shouldn't design it to be "unlimited". A drop down menu on a web page/application shouldn't really be more than two or maybe three levels deep. Anything more, and it will be a total pain for your users.

Considered redesigning your application/information architecture/design?

That said, I do not think you can achieve what you want with pure CSS. My advice is to look into one of the thousands of JavaScript+CSS-menus that exist. They will work for you if you set them up correctly, and provide far better usability than a pure CSS-menu.